# How to run code when Shopify conversion tracking vars exist in URL?

Tags: shopify, conversion-tracking

One can add `note`, `attributes` and `ref` vars to Shopify URLs for conversion tracking as described here:

[Shopify Conversion Tracking Documentation](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/customization/cart/use-permalinks-to-preload-cart#conversion-tracking)

How can I execute extra code if one of these vars exists in the URL? I need to run code right when the URL is initially visited and I also need to run code if the customer completes the purchase.

Supposedly if I have a Shopify Plus plan then I can create my own `layout/checkout.liquid` templates and write some JavaScript code that will do what I need. But we don't have a Shopify Plus plan.

I've also heard that I can write code in `Admin > Settings > Checkout > Order Processing > Additional Scripts` in order to respond to these URL vars but supposedly this option will only allow me to respond on the purchase finished page but not when the URL is initially visited.

Are there any other options? Can I do all of this with a Shopify app?

Answer (score 2):

> Supposedly if I have a Shopify Plus plan then I can create my own
>   layout/checkout.liquid templates and write some JavaScript code that
>   will do what I need. But we don't have a Shopify Plus plan.

Yes, it would be much simpler if you are on Shopify Plus plan. Nonetheless it is still possible to do so.

If you go to

```
Online Store > Preferences > Google Analytics account
```

You can add JavaScript code there that will be loaded on all pages. But it allows limited number of characters , so be aware of that.

To implement the solution, listen to the page load event and then look for any desired variables in the URL. If you find any such variable, you may save it in the [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [Session Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) depending on your use case. For subsequent page visits and page reloads, only write value if does not exist already.

For the scenario when customer completes a purchase, you may add the code in

```
admin > Settings > Checkout > Order Processing > Additional Scripts
```

But make sure to use the [first time accessed](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/orders/status-tracking/first-time-accessed) condition to prevent duplicate processing.

```
{% if first_time_accessed %}
  <!-- Conversion scripts you want to run only once -->
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shopify suggests us to use landing_site_ref to put the condition on thank you page.
The customer comes to your website having this  parameter in their URL

```
http://www.referingsite.com?ref=abc
```

Put following code(dummy sample) on **Additional scripts** of Checkout Section.

```
{% if landing_site_ref == 'abc' %}
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://TestTrack.com/get_order?ORDERID={{order.order_number}}&AMOUNT={{ total_price | money_without_currency }}"></script>
{% endif %}
```

*Note: You can explore **referring_site & landing_site** fields available on Thank You page and use contain condition of Shopify e.g. if landing_site contains 'abc'.*